# Effective degree bound for solvability by radicals

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, nested-radicals, galois-extensions, solvable-groups

Let $P\in{\mathbb Q}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n\geq 3$, and let $\mathbb L$ be the decomposition field of $P$. Denote the Galois group of the extension ${\mathbb L}:{\mathbb Q}$ by $G$. Suppose that $G$ is solvable.

It is well-known then that any root $\alpha$ of $P$ is solvable by radicals, i.e. there is a tower of extensions ${\mathbb K}_0\subseteq {\mathbb K}_1 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq {\mathbb K}_r$  where ${\mathbb K}_0={\mathbb Q}$, $\alpha\in {\mathbb K}_r$ and for $1\leq i \leq r$, ${\mathbb K}_i$ is an elementary radical extension of ${\mathbb K}_{i-1}$ : ${\mathbb K}_i={\mathbb K}_{i-1}({\theta_i}^{m_i})$ for some $\theta_i\in{\mathbb K}_{i-1}$ and $m_i\geq 2$. Denote by $D$ the total degree of the extension ${\mathbb K}_r:{\mathbb Q}$.

**Question.** Is there a bound $f(n)$, depending only on $n$, such that in the tower construction above, we may take $D\leq f(n)$ ?

Heuristics for it : this is true for $n\leq 4$ : trivially $f(2)=2$, and we have $f(3)\leq 2\times 3\times 2$ (if we use Lagrange's method as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#cite_note-36, we need $2$ for $j=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$, the third root of unity, and $3\times 2$ for the rest) and $f(4)\leq 2f(3)$ (since the method described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#Galois_theory_and_factorization reduces solving a quartic to taking a square root and solving a cubic).

Heuristics against it : the proof I know of the fact that $\alpha$ is solvable by radicals when $G$ is solvable, relies on the Kronecker-Weber theorem. Now, if you look at the simplest case of this theorem, where you have to include a quadratic field ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{d})$ in a cyclotomic field $C_m={\mathbb Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}})$, clearly a given $C_m$ can contain $\sqrt{d}$ for only finitely many square-free $d$'s, so that $m$ necessarily gets larger as $d$ gets larger.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. $L/\Bbb{Q}$ is a solvable extension of degree dividing $n!$, so $L(\zeta_{n!})/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{n!})$ is a tower of abelian prime degree (ie. $p$-th root extensions with $p\le n$, see Kummer theory) and of degree $\le n!$.   $\zeta_{n!}$ is also in a tower of $p$-th root extensions but the degree of it depends solely on $n$ not on $L$, irrelevant here. That's it you have a bound depending only on $n$.

Comment: @reuns As far as I know, Kummer theory holds only for abelian extensions, not solvable ones. The extension $L(\zeta_{n!})/{\mathbb Q}(\zeta_{n!})$ is not abelian in general, only solvable.

Comment: Solvable = tower of abelian extensions

Comment: I think reuns got it. Won't Kummer's theorem settle this in the affirmative? Here
$$\Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{L}_0\subset \Bbb{L}_1\subset\cdots \Bbb{L}_r$$
is a tower of cyclic extension with prime degrees $[\Bbb{L}_i:\Bbb{L}_{i-1}]=p_i$. If $m$ is the least common multiple of the $p_i$s and $\zeta_m$ the appropriate root of unity, then, by Kummer,
$$\Bbb{Q}\subseteq \Bbb{L}_0(\zeta_m)\subseteq\Bbb{L}_1(\zeta_m)\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\Bbb{L}_r(\zeta_m)$$ is a tower of root extensions, no?

Comment: At each step both $\Bbb{L}_i$ and $\Bbb{L}_{i-1}(\zeta_m)$ are Galois extensions of $\Bbb{L}_{i-1}$. Either the former is contained in the latter, or the two extensions are linearly disjoint, and in the latter case $\Bbb{L}_i(\zeta_m)/\Bbb{L}_{i-1}(\zeta_m)$ is also Galois of degree $p_i$ et cetera.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, just that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\Bbb{Q}$ is not purely radical, not of the form $K(a^{1/d})/K$ with $x^d-a\in K[x]$ irreducible, that's why I add $i$, by Kummer $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5,i)/\Bbb{Q}(i)$ is radical, and at the end I obtain a double factorial bound (which can be obviously improved a bit)

Comment: @reuns I don't think $\zeta_5$ is a problem because it is quadratic over $\sqrt{5}$. But, you are right, getting that extension at the bottom, $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\Bbb{Q}$, as a radical extension requires more care than I indicated. Like including all roots of unity of order $p-1$ for all $p$. Recursively.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes very bad example, I should have said $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\Bbb{Q}$ is not radical whereas $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7,\zeta_3)/\Bbb{Q}$ is

Comment: That's a better example. I totally agree @reuns. I was careless with that bottom layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A Galois extension is solvable iff it is at the top of a tower of abelian extensions (the definition of solvable Galois group)
- Any abelian extension of degree $m$ is radical if the base field contains $\zeta_m$ (Kummer theory)
- By induction on $m$, $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_4,\ldots,\zeta_m)/\Bbb{Q}$ is a radical extension, of degree $\le m!$
- $L$ is the splitting field of a rational polynomial of degree $n$ so $[L:\Bbb{Q}]\le n!$
- You assume that $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$ is solvable, so $L/\Bbb{Q}$ is a tower of abelian extensions, each of degree $\le n!$
- thus $L(\zeta_3,\ldots,\zeta_{n!})/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\ldots,\zeta_{n!})$ is a radical extension of degree $\le n!$ and $$L(\zeta_3,\ldots,\zeta_{n!})/\Bbb{Q}$$ is a radical extension of degree $\le f(n)=(n!)! \cdot n!$